# How to customize hover in bokeh

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

[enter image description here][1]I am using bokeh to show the babynames info on the USA map. Now I draw the map, I want to use hover to show babynames. But I cannot change the connect in hover. How can I do?
my file name is df_latlon

Here are my code:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.sampledata import us_states
us_states = us_states.data.copy()

state_xs = [us_states[code]["lons"] for code in us_states]
state_ys = [us_states[code]["lats"] for code in us_states]
name=df_latlon["Name"]
T = "pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,save"

p = figure(title="Top 1 name of every state form 1910 to 2014", tools=T,
           toolbar_location="left", plot_width=3000, plot_height=1300)

p.patches(state_xs, state_ys, fill_alpha=0.3,
        line_color="blue", line_width=1.5)

x = df_latlon["lon"]
y = df_latlon["lat"]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    name=df_latlon["Name"],
    gender=df_latlon["Gender"]
    ))
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@name"),("Gender","@gender")])


output_file("statenametop1.html")


show(p)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIMT8.png 
 This is a screenshot of my file

Comment: Please add sample data to your dataframe `df_latlon`.

Comment: Thank you！Now I add my screenshot of my sample data

Comment: always put data as text - so we could use it with code to test it and to create solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually add the hover tool to a plot for it to have any effect:

```
p.add_tools(hover)
```